# No module named virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opencv, installation

I'm trying to install openCV on my new Mac (Mojave).So, I'm following this   [tutorial](https://medium.com/@shunzhema/installing-opencv-and-python-3-7-using-homebrew-on-macos-high-sierra-with-virtual-wrapper-640e31b7d390).

I want to create a new virtual whit this command:

```
mkvirtualenv cv3 -p python3
```

But sometimes I get the following output on my terminal:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/keyone/code/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/python3.7
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/keyone/code/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/python (you must use /Users/keyone/code/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/python3.7)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
```

or this output:

```
-bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

This is how my .bash_profile file looks like:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/code/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/code
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
```

I looked on stack overflow to find a solution, but nothing is working for me. virtualen, python etc. are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `virtualenv -p python3 envname` as it work for me in mac book : D

Comment: Tanks for your answer. This worked for me. But when I now type in ```workon cv3``` or ```deactive``` in my terminal I get the following output twice ```-bash: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory```
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: try using `source deactivate` hope it works for you :D

Comment: It's not working. It says always ```-bash: deactivate: No such file or directory```

Comment: Please make sure that you have created a dir name cv3 and it present on same working directory where you are working, if not try using `mkvirtualenv cv3` and then type `workon` this will show you all the directory present on your project.

Comment: Please refer to this **[link](http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/)** your solution, i hope it works for you: D